# when running python script ,getting module not found error

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, importerror, git-submodules

I am having one project folder with subfolders inside it mainly tools and lib.
In one of python file, I am trying to import one file from lib which is at same level as tool folder. but the script is giving an error of module not found.

Below is the replica of folder structure:

```
sever
├── tools
│   └── file.py
└── lib
    └── some_file.py
```

can anyone soggest me what is the possible error. My server folder contains __init.py, but still I don't know the cause of error or how to rectify that. Any help will be appreciated.

Error code is below:

```
ranjeet@ubuntu:~/Desktop/Connect/server$ tools/protected.py 
/home/ranjeet/Desktop/Connect/server/tools ['/home/ranjeet/Desktop/Connect/server/tools', '/usr/lib/python36.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.6', '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/home/ranjeet/Desktop/Connect/Env/lib/python3.6/site-packages'] 
Traceback (most recent call last): File "tools/protected.py", line 13, in <module> from server.lib.protected import ProtectedPackage 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lib'
```

The file is having following lines code, and raising error in the last line:

```
import base64
import os
import sys
import argparse
import secrets

from lib.protected import Package
```

Comment: kindly attach the full error too

Comment: included the error code in question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from .server.lib.protected import ProtectedPackage
```

Comment: after adding .server.lib.protected, i am getting this following error.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ' __main__ .server'; ' __main__ ' is not a package
```